# Update High Charts every Minute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, highcharts

I Am using jquery High Charts for displaying my data which are temperatures. I am getting updated data every minute and the graph has to show the latest data (update) every minute.
I can do this by simply refreshing the pages but its not the way I want, Is there any other possible way to do it?

Below you can see my graph, scripts and functions.

```
<script>

    time={{ time|safe }}
    machine_temp={{ machine_temp|safe }}
    console.log(machine_temp);
    engine_temp={{ engine_temp|safe }}
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Engine and Machine Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: time
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Engine',
            data: machine_temp
        }, {
            name: 'Machine',
            data: engine_temp
        },]
    });
});
</script>
```

Views.py:

```
def weather_chart_view(request):
     template='graph1.html'
     temperature=Temperature.objects.filter(date=datetime.date.today()).order_by('id')
     time=[]
     machine_temp=[]
     engine_temp=[]
     for temp in temperature:
         time.append(str(temp.Time))
         machine_temp.append(float(temp.machine_temp))
         engine_temp.append(float(temp.engine_temp))
     return render_to_response(template,{'time':time,'machine_temp':machine_temp,'engine_temp':engine_temp},context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

[image]

Comment: I think that better is prepare any script which get data from database and in javascript only call $.getJSON() (each 1 minute) to get data from source. Simple demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this you can try:

```
time={{ time|safe }}
machine_temp={{ machine_temp|safe }}
engine_temp={{ engine_temp|safe }}

function makeChart(elem){
    time={{ time|safe }};
    machine_temp={{ machine_temp|safe }};
    engine_temp={{ engine_temp|safe }};
    $(elem).highcharts({
      // chart code here
    });
}

$(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        makeChart("#container"); // recall in 1 min  60 * 1000 = 60000
    }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: I tried this but this is not executing in every 1 minute

Comment: @Vishnu you can try with this one. other than this you need to have some call where you can update the values in the variables, like ajax.